# What happened to the *= and =* for outer joins in SQL?

Tags: sql, operators, obsolete

I was just curious as to why the `*=` operator for `left outer join` and the '=*' for 'right outer join were taken out of the SQL standard, or, at least not supported by SQL server 2005 and on?  I have read a few other posts on this particular operator and understand that it can give some unexpected results. But if it were semantically equivalent I would think it would be an easier operator to use when having to join multiple tables.  If anything, I would rather use this operator to to dynamically create sql queries as opposed to trying to get the correct word order like:

```
FROM accounts 
LEFT OUTER JOIN customers 
ON accounts.accountnum = customers.accountnum 
LEFT OUTER JOIN products 
ON customers.accountnum = products.accountnum 
AND customers.id = products.customerid
```

where

```
FROM accounts, customers, products
WHERE accounts.accountnum *= customers.accountnum AND
      customers.accountnum *= products.accountnum AND
      customers.id *= products.customer.id
```

would seem to be easier to parse together.

**But back to the real world, what was the idea for these operators if they dont perfom a "true" outer join?**  The term **Short Hand** implies that it should do exactly the same thing, but obviosly not in this case.

Comment: Can you provide a reference to their use?  I've never heard of these operators.  At the bare minimum, I would say they feel too ripe for causing confusion over possible typos...

Comment: @X-Zero: Very common not so long ago, say ten years. SQL-92 support was limited at that time and there is a **lot** of legacy code that uses this join syntax.

Comment: I am pretty sure Oracle versions supported this syntax for a long time...

Comment: I **much prefer** the first style - the ANSI standard style - of JOINs. Why?? With the "legacy" style of just comma-separating a bunch of tables, you are (1) in danger of missing a JOIN condition, thus causing an unwanted cartesian product (and massively increasing the number of rows returned), and (2) cluttering up your WHERE clause with JOIN conditions, so you have a messy assemblage of JOIN condition and actual WHERE conditions. The ANSI style with the explicit JOINs and their JOIN conditions is just that much nicer and clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server MVP K. Brian Kelley does a good job of explaining it here: [Why SQL Server 2005 Doesn't Permit Non-ANSI Style OUTER JOINs](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/brian_kelley/2007/11/01/why-sql-server-2005-doesnt-permit-non-ansi-style-outer-joins/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think they were taken out of the standard. I think they were never in it. They were just a convention that vendors followed until SQL-92 came out and the vendors decided it was worth implementing.

Answer (score 1):

Do a google search for the Chris Date paper, "Outer Join with No Nulls and Fewer Tears", which pre-dates the SQL-92 Standard. Although I couldn't find a free copy online, I did find a document that analyses the paper and gives a nice potted history of outer join in SQL. Note nowadays Date would relation-valued attributes for this kind of query and would urge you to generally avoid outer joins ;)